# Изменить ориентацию экрана

Tags: c#

OC - Windows 10

Использую WPF

Как можно изменить ориентацию экрана Windows 10 программным способом ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это какая платформа?

Comment: @АндрейNOP Windows 10

Comment: Universal Windows Platform?

Comment: @АндрейNOP я думал про операционную систему, WPF

Comment: В таком случае я не понимаю что вы хотите сделать, в Windows экран поворачивается в настройках

Comment: @АндрейNOP хочу не через настройки это сделать, а нажать на `Button` в `WPF` приложении и перевернуть / повернуть и т.д.

Comment: Повернуть что? Всё что находится на экране?

Comment: @АндрейNOP `button1` - перевернуть всё как это делается через настройки (параметры экрана), `button2` - перевернуть отдельное клиентское приложение (например калькулятор)

Answer (score 0):

Код скопирован отсюда: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39288135/rotating-the-display-programmatically

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class Display
    {
        public enum Orientations
        {
            DEGREES_CW_0 = 0,
            DEGREES_CW_90 = 3,
            DEGREES_CW_180 = 2,
            DEGREES_CW_270 = 1
        }

        public static bool Rotate(uint DisplayNumber, Orientations Orientation)
        {
            if(DisplayNumber == 0)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("DisplayNumber", DisplayNumber, "First display is 1.");

            bool result = false;
            DISPLAY_DEVICE d = new DISPLAY_DEVICE();
            DEVMODE dm = new DEVMODE();
            d.cb = Marshal.SizeOf(d);

           if(!NativeMethods.EnumDisplayDevices(null, DisplayNumber-1, ref d, 0))
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("DisplayNumber", DisplayNumber, "Number is greater than connected displays.");

            if (0 != NativeMethods.EnumDisplaySettings(
                d.DeviceName, NativeMethods.ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS, ref dm))
            {
                if ((dm.dmDisplayOrientation + (int)Orientation) % 2 == 1) // Need to swap height and width?
                {
                    int temp = dm.dmPelsHeight;
                    dm.dmPelsHeight = dm.dmPelsWidth;
                    dm.dmPelsWidth = temp;
                }

                switch (Orientation)
                {
                    case Orientations.DEGREES_CW_90:
                        dm.dmDisplayOrientation = NativeMethods.DMDO_270;
                        break;
                    case Orientations.DEGREES_CW_180:
                        dm.dmDisplayOrientation = NativeMethods.DMDO_180;
                        break;
                    case Orientations.DEGREES_CW_270:
                        dm.dmDisplayOrientation = NativeMethods.DMDO_90;
                        break;
                    case Orientations.DEGREES_CW_0:
                        dm.dmDisplayOrientation = NativeMethods.DMDO_DEFAULT;
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }

                DISP_CHANGE ret = NativeMethods.ChangeDisplaySettingsEx(
                    d.DeviceName, ref dm, IntPtr.Zero,
                    DisplaySettingsFlags.CDS_UPDATEREGISTRY, IntPtr.Zero);

                result = ret == 0;
            }

            return result;
        }

        public static void ResetAllRotations()
        {
            try
            {
                uint i = 0;
                while (++i <= 64)
                {
                    Rotate(i, Orientations.DEGREES_CW_0);
                }
            }
            catch(ArgumentOutOfRangeException ex)
            {
                // Everything is fine, just reached the last display
            }
        }
    }

    internal class NativeMethods
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        internal static extern DISP_CHANGE ChangeDisplaySettingsEx(
            string lpszDeviceName, ref DEVMODE lpDevMode, IntPtr hwnd,
            DisplaySettingsFlags dwflags, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        internal static extern bool EnumDisplayDevices(
            string lpDevice, uint iDevNum, ref DISPLAY_DEVICE lpDisplayDevice,
            uint dwFlags);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        internal static extern int EnumDisplaySettings(
            string lpszDeviceName, int iModeNum, ref DEVMODE lpDevMode);

        public const int DMDO_DEFAULT = 0;
        public const int DMDO_90 = 1;
        public const int DMDO_180 = 2;
        public const int DMDO_270 = 3;

        public const int ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS = -1;

    }

    // See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183565(v=vs.85).aspx
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    internal struct DEVMODE
    {
        public const int CCHDEVICENAME = 32;
        public const int CCHFORMNAME = 32;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = CCHDEVICENAME)]
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(0)]
        public string dmDeviceName;
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(32)]
        public Int16 dmSpecVersion;
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(34)]
        public Int16 dmDriverVersion;
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(36)]
        public Int16 dmSize;
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(38)]
        public Int16 dmDriverExtra;
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(40)]
        public DM dmFields;

        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(44)]
        Int16 dmOrientation;
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(46)]
        Int16 dmPaperSize;
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(48)]
        Int16 dmPaperLength;
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(50)]
        Int16 dmPaperWidth;
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(52)]
        Int16 dmScale;
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(54)]
        Int16 dmCopies;
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(56)]
        Int16 dmDefaultSource;
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(58)]
        Int16 dmPrintQuality;

        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(44)]
        public POINTL dmPosition;
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(52)]
        public Int32 dmDisplayOrientation;
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(56)]
        public Int32 dmDisplayFixedOutput;

        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(60)]
        public short dmColor;
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(62)]
        public short dmDuplex;
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(64)]
        public short dmYResolution;
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(66)]
        public short dmTTOption;
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(68)]
        public short dmCollate;
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(72)]
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = CCHFORMNAME)]
        public string dmFormName;
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(102)]
        public Int16 dmLogPixels;
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(104)]
        public Int32 dmBitsPerPel;
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(108)]
        public Int32 dmPelsWidth;
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(112)]
        public Int32 dmPelsHeight;
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(116)]
        public Int32 dmDisplayFlags;
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(116)]
        public Int32 dmNup;
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(120)]
        public Int32 dmDisplayFrequency;
    }

    // See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183569(v=vs.85).aspx
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    internal struct DISPLAY_DEVICE
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
        public int cb;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)]
        public string DeviceName;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 128)]
        public string DeviceString;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
        public DisplayDeviceStateFlags StateFlags;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 128)]
        public string DeviceID;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 128)]
        public string DeviceKey;
    }

    // See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/dd162807(v=vs.85).aspx
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct POINTL
    {
        long x;
        long y;
    }

    internal enum DISP_CHANGE : int
    {
        Successful = 0,
        Restart = 1,
        Failed = -1,
        BadMode = -2,
        NotUpdated = -3,
        BadFlags = -4,
        BadParam = -5,
        BadDualView = -6
    }

    // http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Enums/DisplayDeviceStateFlags.html
    [Flags()]
    internal enum DisplayDeviceStateFlags : int
    {
        /// <summary>The device is part of the desktop.</summary>
        AttachedToDesktop = 0x1,
        MultiDriver = 0x2,
        /// <summary>The device is part of the desktop.</summary>
        PrimaryDevice = 0x4,
        /// <summary>Represents a pseudo device used to mirror application drawing for remoting or other purposes.</summary>
        MirroringDriver = 0x8,
        /// <summary>The device is VGA compatible.</summary>
        VGACompatible = 0x10,
        /// <summary>The device is removable; it cannot be the primary display.</summary>
        Removable = 0x20,
        /// <summary>The device has more display modes than its output devices support.</summary>
        ModesPruned = 0x8000000,
        Remote      = 0x4000000,
        Disconnect  = 0x2000000
    }

    // http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/ChangeDisplaySettingsFlags.html
    [Flags()]
    internal enum DisplaySettingsFlags : int
    {
        CDS_NONE = 0,
        CDS_UPDATEREGISTRY      = 0x00000001,
        CDS_TEST                = 0x00000002,
        CDS_FULLSCREEN          = 0x00000004,
        CDS_GLOBAL              = 0x00000008,
        CDS_SET_PRIMARY         = 0x00000010,
        CDS_VIDEOPARAMETERS     = 0x00000020,
        CDS_ENABLE_UNSAFE_MODES = 0x00000100,
        CDS_DISABLE_UNSAFE_MODES= 0x00000200,
        CDS_RESET               = 0x40000000,
        CDS_RESET_EX            = 0x20000000,
        CDS_NORESET             = 0x10000000
    }

    [Flags()]
    internal enum DM : int
    {
        Orientation         = 0x00000001,
        PaperSize           = 0x00000002,
        PaperLength         = 0x00000004,
        PaperWidth          = 0x00000008,
        Scale               = 0x00000010,
        Position            = 0x00000020,
        NUP                 = 0x00000040,
        DisplayOrientation  = 0x00000080,
        Copies              = 0x00000100,
        DefaultSource       = 0x00000200,
        PrintQuality        = 0x00000400,
        Color               = 0x00000800,
        Duplex              = 0x00001000,
        YResolution         = 0x00002000,
        TTOption            = 0x00004000,
        Collate             = 0x00008000,
        FormName            = 0x00010000,
        LogPixels           = 0x00020000,
        BitsPerPixel        = 0x00040000,
        PelsWidth           = 0x00080000,
        PelsHeight          = 0x00100000,
        DisplayFlags        = 0x00200000,
        DisplayFrequency    = 0x00400000,
        ICMMethod           = 0x00800000,
        ICMIntent           = 0x01000000,
        MediaType           = 0x02000000,
        DitherType          = 0x04000000,
        PanningWidth        = 0x08000000,
        PanningHeight       = 0x10000000,
        DisplayFixedOutput  = 0x20000000
    }
```

Использование:

```
Display.Rotate(1, Display.Orientations.DEGREES_CW_180);
```

Так же есть функция `ResetAllRotations()` для ресета настроек для всех подключенных экранов.